# Bootstrap data-spy not firing off

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a profile website for myself and have a ***'decent'*** concept up and running.

However it seems as if my navbar's data-spy either isn't firing off or if there is something wrong with my html / css.

**[This](https://codepen.io/Todai/pen/grKvjO)** is a pen with the html / css.
This is the body (relevant data-spy reference):

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="50">
```

This is how I've set up the navbar:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <div class="navbar-header">

    <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBar-target" class="navbar-toggle"> 
    <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
    <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
    <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBar-target">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <a href="#top" > About </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#portfolio" > Portfolio </a>
      </li>
      <li class>
        <a href="#contact" > Contact </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And here is some of the relevant css:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #333;
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #000000 !important;
}

#navbar {
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd;
} 

.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 9vw 10vw
  margin-top: 8vw;
  margin-right: 15vw;
  margin-bottom: 8vw;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1vw solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4vw;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.nav>li {
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.nav>li>a:focus,
.nav>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #722872;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav>li a:hover {
  color: #722872;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

As mentioned, a full working example is on the **[code-pen](https://codepen.io/Todai/pen/grKvjO)**

Comment: Do you have any CSS for ".navbar-nav>.active>a"? Have you included the Bootstrap JS?

Comment: That was it The .active wasn't included! Have been looking around for awhile to find this!
How can I give you any +?

Comment: I've made an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Bootstrap doesn't include a default style for the active nav element. Need to create a style for `.navbar-nav>.active>a`